# Embeding streaming player inside my app IOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I'm trying to create an iPhone app which plays local radio station in my district. I found this player to work best for me :

https://github.com/DigitalDJ/AudioStreamer

When testing it against my requirements it did the best without any doubt.

I thought I'll use this players API and it should be straightforward(not really for a newbie). How exactly I do that is where I'm stuck now. Because when I run the player original project it runs smooth, but when I copy code inside Classes to my app, this is what happens :

[image]

Ok, I've been developing some apps(test apps) for two weeks maybe and I lack experience.

How do you usually embed/import other projects code into your code and user the other codes api?

**EDIT**

So per Sunil Pandey answer, this cannot be run using IOS SDK version 5.0?

**EDIT 2 :**

I feel like I'm really close now, have this one issue :

```
Receiver 'AudioStreamer' for instance message is a forward declaration
```

It's declared in my h file. as `AudioStreamer *streamer`

Comment: Did you #import the AudioStreamer class ? Did you include in your project all required frameworks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said Sunil Pandey, ARC mecanism is enabled for your project. With ARC, your project require at least iOS4 on the phone.

I would suggest you to disable ARC for the file you imported from the third party librairy. So you can keep using ARC in your own code (this mean, you never use retain, release, autorelease).
To disable ARC for each file of your AudioStreamer library, refer to [How can I disable ARC for a single file in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project)

Answer (score 1):

You must have implemented ARC inside your project. that's why it is giving you this error.
If you are using ARC then only way to use this project library is to create a static library of your AudioStreamer lib and then import it inside your app

Or

If you don't want to use ARC inside your app then you can turn it off by following method

select your target -> Build Setting -> Apple LLVM Compiler 3.0 - Language

set Objective c Automatic Reference Counting to NO